# PHP - Get string from array

Tags: php, arrays, string, get, output

How would I be able to get OUTPUT from this array, I have searched for ages and I cant find anything. I thought it might be '$array->ext->test1' but that didn't work.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ext] => test1 [type] => test2 [url] => OUTPUT ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $arr[0]['url'];
```

Simply as that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try and go read some manuals (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

```
$array[0]['url']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get the values:

```
echo $arr[0]['ext'];
echo $arr[0]['type'];
echo $arr[0]['url'];
```